# How can I press "Start" windows button via python and win32api/pywinauto?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywinauto

I need to hide "Start menu" window via python if it's open.
Clicking on coordinates does not work for me because script will be running on Windows 11.
Also, it would be nice if I could check if "Start menu" is visible etc.

UPD:
Code that works now.

```
desktop = Desktop(backend='uia')
start_menu = desktop.window(title='Start', control_type='Window')
if start_menu.exists():
    pywinauto.keyboard.send_keys('{LWIN down}{LWIN up}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is nothing special in Win11 (I haven't tried it yet), this is how it works on Win10:

```
from pywinauto import Desktop

taskbar = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Taskbar", control_type="Pane")
# taskbar.dump_tree() # print the subtree like it should be coded with pywinauto

# we will check if "Start" window exists later (it's kind of locator)
start_window = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Start", control_type="Window")

# wait up to 2 seconds until window exists or return False
# if window already exists, it returns True almost immediately
if start_window.exists(timeout=2):
    # hide the menu
    taskbar.child_window(title="Start", control_type="Button").click()
```

Comment: I getting an error in the last line on ".click()" method: ```pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Taskbar', 'control_type': 'Pane', 'top_level_only': True, 'backend': 'uia'}```

Comment: Maybe your OS language is not English so "Taskbar" may be translated. Please find the correct name in a list returned by `Desktop(backend="uia").windows()` or in more details: `print([w.window_text() for w in Desktop(backend="uia").windows()])`.

Comment: It's correct I think. Here is list: ```[<uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Taskbar', Pane, 1191006032>, <uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe - python  test.py', Dialog, 829543732>, <uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'C:\Users\testerauto\Desktop\test.py - Notepad++', Dialog, -813181794>, <uia_controls.ListViewWrapper - '', ListBox, -1686743987>, <uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Program Manager', Pane, 388209819>]```

Comment: With "Start menu" opened i have ```<uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Start', Dialog, -622185534>``` in list

Comment: Also, when I have start menu displayed I got no error but nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, nothing happens because you need to change the condition to `if start_window.exists(timeout=2):` to hide the menu. It was my fault. But regarding the first `ElementNotFoundError` this is very strange. I don't see such error on my Win10 20H2. In your case it should fail on simplest statement: `taskbar.wrapper_object()` Please confirm it.

Comment: Also it's interesting what do `sys.version` and `sys.getwindowsversion()` return?

Comment: ```3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)]
sys.getwindowsversion(major=10, minor=0, build=22000, platform=2, service_pack='')```

Comment: Now i fixed my issue like this `desktop = Desktop(backend='uia')
        start_menu = desktop.window(title='Start', control_type='Window')
        if start_menu.exists():
            pywinauto.keyboard.send_keys('{LWIN down}{LWIN up}')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.hotkey('winleft')
```

[Source](https://datatofish.com/control-keyboard-python/)
[Keyboard Keys](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys)

Comment: First I need to check if the start menu is displayed